# Stream a twitter list using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I have a problem while I want to stream a specific public Twitter list using Tweepy. I can stream a specific user, but the filter follow doesn't work in this case. I have quite a long list of accounts I would like to stream to do further analysis, so I prepared a list with all of them on twitter. Does anyone know how to handle that?

My code is as follows:

```py
import tweepy
import sys

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.id_str)
        # if "retweeted_status" attribute exists, flag this tweet as a retweet.
        is_retweet = hasattr(status, "retweeted_status")

        # check if text has been truncated
        if hasattr(status,"extended_tweet"):
            text = status.extended_tweet["full_text"]
        else:
            text = status.text

        # check if this is a quote tweet.
        is_quote = hasattr(status, "quoted_status")
        quoted_text = ""
        if is_quote:
            # check if quoted tweet's text has been truncated before recording it
            if hasattr(status.quoted_status,"extended_tweet"):
                quoted_text = status.quoted_status.extended_tweet["full_text"]
            else:
                quoted_text = status.quoted_status.text

        # remove characters that might cause problems with csv encoding
        remove_characters = [",","\n"]
        for c in remove_characters:
            text.replace(c," ")
            quoted_text.replace(c, " ")

        with open("out.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (status.created_at,status.user.screen_name,is_retweet,is_quote,text,quoted_text))

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print("Encountered streaming error (", status_code, ")")
        sys.exit()

consumer_key = "..."
consumer_secret = "..."
access_token = "..."
access_token_secret = "..."


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

if (not api):
    print("Authentication failed!")
    sys.exit(-1)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener,tweet_mode='extended')
with open("out.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write("date,user,is_retweet,is_quote,text,quoted_text\n")
myStream.filter(follow=['52286608'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `follow` parameter with a comma-separated list of user IDs. From the Twitter API documentation:

```
follow
A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose Tweets should be delivered on the stream. Following protected users is not supported. For each user specified, the stream will contain:

- Tweets created by the user.
- Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
- Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
- Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
- Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).

The stream will not contain:

- Tweets mentioning the user (e.g. “Hello @twitterapi!”).
- Manual Retweets created without pressing a Retweet button (e.g. “RT @twitterapi The API is great”).
- Tweets by protected users.
```

You can follow up to 5000 IDs this way.

Note that the API you are connecting has been superseded by the [v2 filtered stream API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/introduction), but Tweepy does not currently support that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I thought about it but since i have many many accounts to stream i tried to omit this option. I would have a problem with matching ids to the users i've already added to my list. Do you have any idea how can I do that quite fast? That would help. thx

Comment: Those are hard limits, so unfortunately that's really the only thing you can do. The users/lookup endpoint supports multiple (up to 100) accounts in a single request https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-lookup